# Using Mako In Windows

Tags: python

I plan to use wsgi + mako in Windows.

I install mako using

```
C:\wsgi>c:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install.exe Mako
```

No error. I get

```
Finished processing dependencies for Mako
```

at end of the message.

I check my Python directory, I am having the following structure :

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mako-0.2.5-py2.6.egg
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mako-0.2.5-py2.6.egg\EGG-INFO
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mako-0.2.5-py2.6.egg\mako
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mako-0.2.5-py2.6.egg\mako\ext
```

I run the following code HelloWorld.py

```
from mako.template import Template

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    mytemplate = Template("hello, ${name}!")
    output = mytemplate.render(name="jack")

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

I get the following error log :

```
[Fri Feb 05 16:11:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:/wsgi/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Feb 05 16:11:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from mako.template import Template
[Fri Feb 05 16:11:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named mako.template
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few things to try

- make sure you're using python2.6
- try `import mako` and see if you get a similar error
- if mako imports correctly look at the value of `repr(mako)` and make sure it corresponds to the path you have.

Comment: When I restart my machine, everything works fine. I forget I am in Windows :)